# Prove that $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X.$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

> Let $\mathcal C$ be any class of subsets of a non-empty set $X$ and let $Y \subseteq X.$ Let $\mathcal S \left ( \mathcal C \cap Y \right )$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $Y$ generated by $\mathcal C \cap Y.$ Let $$\mathcal S : = \left \{ E \cup \left ( B \cap Y^c \right )\ \big |\ E \in \mathcal S 
>  \left ( \mathcal C \cap Y \right ), B \in \mathcal C \right \}.$$ Show that $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ such that $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal S$ and $\mathcal S \cap Y = \mathcal S \left ( \mathcal C \right ) \cap Y.$

I tried to show first that $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ but I have stuck to prove the very first property which is $\varphi, X \in \mathcal S.$ Can anybody help me in this regard?

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. If $\mathcal C=\{Y^{c}\}$ the $E \cup (B \cap Y^{c})=E \cup Y^{c} \neq \emptyset$ for any $B \in \mathcal C$ so the empty set does not belong to $\mathcal S$ unless $Y=X$.

Comment: Yeah. But it was given by I.K. Rana in his lecture in measure theory. I shall share the link in a minute.

Comment: See here https://youtu.be/zAcrrC2QHrE $25:36$

Comment: Nobody is perfect, right? We all make mistakes. @mathmaniac.

Answer (score 0):

I am also going through I.K. Rana's lectures and exercises. There is a typo in the slides in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAcrrC2QHrE when defining $\mathcal S$ $$\mathcal S : = \left \{ E \cup \left ( B \cap Y^c \right )\ \big |\ E \in \mathcal S 
 \left ( \mathcal C \cap Y \right ), B \in \mathcal C \right \}.$$

If you go to the course exercises for Lectures 1-4 on https://archive.nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/111101005/downloads/Lecture1-4.pdf The set $\mathcal S$ should be $$\mathcal S : = \left \{ E \cup \left ( B \cap Y^c \right )\ \big |\ E \in \mathcal S 
 \left ( \mathcal C \cap Y \right ), B \in \mathcal S (\mathcal C )\right \}.$$
so
$ B := \emptyset \in \mathcal S (\mathcal C ) \implies \emptyset \in \mathcal S$